# Mismatched return type error when returning a custom type from a function with a loop with an if

Tags: rust

I am porting of [Devon Crawford's time-lapse plugin](https://github.com/DevonCrawford/Timelapse-Auto-Ramp-Photoshop-Plugin) from Java to Rust.

My question is in relation to the proRaw.java file and the `getPrevImage` method

```java
public Image getPrevImage(Image currIMG) {
    return images.get(currIMG.getListNum() - 1);
}
```

This is my Rust version:

```
pub fn get_previous_image(current: Image, p: PhotoXMP) -> Image {
    let v = p.image_sequence.into_iter();
    for x in v {
        if x.xmp_path == current.xmp_path
            && x.image_path == current.image_path
            && x.exposure == current.exposure
            && x.aperture == current.aperture
            && x.iso == current.iso
            && x.list == current.list
            && x.white_balance == current.white_balance
            && x.ratio == current.ratio
            && x.shutter == current.shutter
        {
            return x;
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Image {
    xmp_path: String,
    image_path: String,
    iso: i32,
    list: u32,
    white_balance: u32,
    ratio: u64,
    aperture: u64,
    shutter: u64,
    exposure: u64,
}

pub struct PhotoXMP {
    util: Util,
    image_sequence: Vec<Image>,
    exposure_sequence: Vec<ExposeChange>,
    temperature_sequence: Vec<TempChange>,
    exposure_increment: i64,
    start: i32,
    end: i32,
}
```

On the `getPrevImage` method, the compiler gives the error "expected struct 'Image', found '()'

Here is the link to the GitHub repo if anyone wants to look at it and suggest edits and changes https://github.com/AlvinKuruvilla/PhotoXMP

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. I've deleted the unrelated requests for code-review. You may be interested in posting your (working!) code to [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: What is the returned value when your loop **never matches anything**?

Comment: You probably want something like `p.image_sequence.into_iter().find(|x| x == &current).expect("Nothing found")`

Comment: Thanks Shepmaster, I believed that solved the issue here is the link to the GitHub repo if you have any suggestions for improvements. https://github.com/AlvinKuruvilla/PhotoXMP The code is not really finished so I will probably submit for code review once I have an MVP and my api is a little more consolidated